# Create a workflow that is triggered on a daily basis

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-tasks-list

I have a list of 7 tasks that need to be performed by 7 people on a daily basis. All tasks have different deadlines during the day. Every day, I would like the 7 people to get a reminder to perform the task and then check the box in SharePoint when they finish.

What I think I need is a workflow containing the 7 tasks, but it needs to refresh every workday. I do not have access to SharePoint Designer, so I'm looking for a way around this.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance,

Karel

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to SharePoint Designer then there is no way for you to create workflow (unless you are using some 3rd party WF designer like Nintex). SharePoint Designer is free download so  you can install it on your client machine (the SP Designer may be blocked on your farm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SharePoint online, then you could leverage on Flows, using time as a trigger.
Almost like site workflows, but doing it without SPD inside the browser.

only applies to SharePoint online.